# Heat shield for pantry cabinet?

Tags: cabinets, stove, heat, range

The wonderful designers of my kitchen installed a tall (oak) pantry cabinet next to the range.  I am concerned that this is a fire hazard.  Is there anything I can do to mitigate the heat from the stove top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Range hood vented to outdoors.
2. Overlay heat resistant materials over cabinet, CBU/porcelain tile or CBU/stainless steel sheeting

CBU = Cement Backer Unit AKA Cement Backer Board

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all appliances have published minimum clearance requirements. You should be able to look up your model online and find the installation instructions, including said requirements.

E.g. this [randomly picked Kitchenaid gas range](http://www.kitchenaid.com/digitalassets/KGSS907SSS/Dimension%20Guide_EN.pdf) requires 24"-30" clearance above the stove and 5" from the side of the stove to a wall, among other requirements.

If your setup meets the manufacturer's recommendations, you are almost certainly OK and I wouldn't worry about it. If not, you could try some of @HerrBag's suggestions or ideally remedy the situation properly by fixing the layout.